# Connecting Menu Items to slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is there any way i can connect menu items in WordPress to sliders. Like on this website https://www.graffdiamonds.com/, when you hover your mouse on menu item, the slider changes.

any theme in wordpress or any jquery plugin etc. to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make it. But first you have to make design like that using some js library and convert it to wordpress.